# Ionic2 - Keyboard Open/Close State Detection

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular, ionic2

I'm looking for a simple solution to detect whether keyboard on mobile device has been opened / closed (stack: Ionic2, Angular2).

Does Ionic propagate any 'keyboard-open' or 'keyboard-close' class out into the body/html?

Answer (score 4):

Keyboard is native to mobile device.So you need native plugins to check its functionalities. Install the cordova plugin and ionic native typings as below

```
ionic plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
npm install --save @ionic-native/keyboard
```

Add the below lines of code to check the keyboard open and close

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) {

...
//Observes when the keyboard is shown
this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow(); 

   //Observes when the keyboard is hidden
   this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide();
```

}

Comment: did you test this code. I mean can we call a dependency method outside of our class function? `this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow()` must be inside a function or assign the result to a property. then what is the right way?

Comment: @Khurram, the method should be inside a function.

Answer (score 1):

Ionic does not emit `keyboard-open` or `keyboard-close`, but there is [ionic-plugin-keyboard](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard) which does just that. It will fire `native.keyboardshow` and `native.keyboardhide` events. You can also query the `Keyboard.isVisible` property.

Answer (score 0):

ugly answer but works like charm:

```
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core';
public IsKeyboardOpen:boolean=false;
    constructor(public ngZ:NgZone)
    {
        var innerHeight=window.innerHeight;
        window.onresize = (e) =>
       {
        this.ngZ.run(() => 
        {
          if(window.innerHeight< innerHeight)
          {
            this.IsKeyboardOpen=true;
          }
          else
          {
            this.IsKeyboardOpen=false;
          }
        });
    };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/

```
window.addEventListener('keyboardWillShow', (event) => {
    // Describe your logic which will be run each time when keyboard is about to be shown.
    console.log(event.keyboardHeight);
});
```